# rails truncate method adds special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, special-characters, truncate, sanitize

I have this html text:

```
<p> I'm a html &nbsp; text</p>
```

To show it on my web page, I first sanitize it and remove the tags:

```
sanitize(best_practice.milestone.description, :tags=>[])
```

I then shows ok, the `&nbsp;` is removed.

But if I decide to truncate the text like this:

```
sanitize(best_practice.milestone.description, :tags=>[]).truncate(30)
```

The `&nbsp;` is visible again on my web page. All the special chars will actually be visible.

What can I do to avoid truncate to make this special chars visible?

Comment: I have been trying this for a year. Good question.

Comment: Actually I would be very surprised is sanitize strips the &nbsp; - I thought it would only strip a default set of html tags, if you don't tell it to do otherwise.

Comment: Sanitize doesn't strip the &nbsp; but at least it is not visible in my html page. After using truncate, it is visible, which is strange because "truncate" should only cut the string without doing anything else.

Comment: Don't you just need to add a `.html_safe` at the end, i.e. `sanitize(best_practice.milestone.description, :tags=>[]).truncate(30).html_safe`? That will leave it but at least not escape it so that it is visible as text.

Comment: Indeed, the solution was so simple as this! i had tried it after sanitize, as I first thought the problem came from there but not after truncate. Thanks! Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dealing with *sanitize* helpers and truncation can be tricky. There are a lot of different *sanitize* helpers: h, CGI::escapeHTML, sanitize, strip_tags, html_safe, etc. Sanitization and truncation do not work well together if a string is truncated between an opening and a closing tag or right in the middle of a special HTML character.

The following statement seems to work

```
sanitize(text, :tags=>[]).truncate(30, :separator => " ").html_safe
```

The trick is to a pass a :separator option to truncate text at a natural break.